# What is the History of foiling in MTG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Foiling has changed over the years, and it made me wonder about all of the types and processes of foiling, and when they happened.

The big thing that made me wonder, is that older foiling is considerably different than modern day foiling. Along with using different types of foiling, they also appeared to have extra symbols, such as a comet going along the bottom.

Comment: This youtube video goes into extreme detail on Magic's (current) history of foiling, and is a great watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50b5x1GM-jQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Urza's Legacy was the first set to feature foil cards available in booster packs. However, the previous set (Urza's Saga) had a foil prerelease promo card. [[Source](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/arcana/first-foil-prerelease-card-2004-07-26)]

From Urza's Legacy until 8th Edition, the "old-style" foil treatment (with the Wizards of the Coast shooting star across the bottom) was used. The process to create these cards involved a problem where certain foils would include a "cutline": a seam in the foil treatment across the face of the card (see below for an example; the seam runs through the shark in the background).

[image]

Details on the modern foil treatment can be found here: [Where the Foil Goes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/where-foil-goes-2013-02-26).

Note that special releases (e.g., the "From the Vault" series) may use a different foiling process from standard sets. [[Source](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/sneak-peek-vault-dragons-2008-08-08), search for "varnish"]

Additionally, many promos have unique foil treatments, like this Sudden Shock:

[image: Sudden Shock]

Comment: The first foil card I remember seeing was inPlaneshift expansion(2001):it was a ShiftingSky.Well,this is only a clue about the whole history of foil cards,but it is quite difficult to reconstruct the whole story here,by myself only.However,it is not a complicated operation to search online which was the first expansion to offer foil cards,Urza's Legacy.I remember that foil basic lands could also be found.ThatOldTimeFoiling was a little different:the whole foil card looked more sparkling,even if everything was less detailed and refined than today.Anyway,that's all,as for my knowledge,of course!

Comment: I wrote clearly that my answer was partial,from the beginning.My answer never wanted to be"the best".I replied knowing that mine was not definitive information,and that only together with other answers could they,taken together,constitute the pieces of a great mosaic representing" Foil History",by force of circumstances,very rich in"subjective "details